# Changing bot from Node to C# in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

When I first set up my bot in Azure I was new to Azure and the Bot Framework. After some reading, I learned that my QnA Bot can be set up in Azure via Node or C#. I guess I must have accidentally selected Node somewhere because that is how my code is when I look at my bot in Azure- Is there a way to change this to C# after the fact?

Comment: Your best bet is to just recreate the bot

Comment: You might be able to do the best of both worlds; create a new bot and replace all the files in your “current” bot with those of the node bot.  Note, I haven’t tested that.  Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way in Azure to change an application type from Node to C#.  This would be a manual operation.